# Benefits of neck extension training?

Tags: neck

Does training the neck have any purpose other than for combat sports and getting the thick neck look (which I assume is desirable when heavily bulking so your head doesn't look too small?)?

For example, might it help with forward head posture, relieve tightness in the neck or shoulders or be desirable for other common daily activities?

I'm just starting a strength training program that does quite a bit of neck extension work and I'm wondering if I should omit it.

Comment: read somewhere that it makes your voice deeper but don't think that works... I do combat sports so I find it quiet useful other than resilience considerations I don't think there is a broad purpose for general health and everyday life.

Comment: I think it's just for looks in Greyskull. I remember hearing the author being quoted something like "the neck is the one muscle people can see even if you're in a suit".

Answer (score 2):

Neck training is really important for your health and posture. Daily activities such as driving and sitting in front of a computer cause your head to slightly lean forward and your neck to go out of alignment. In time, this contributes to a poor posture and makes the muscles and ligaments in your neck and shoulders stretch. Permanent tension in this area can also lead to headaches and migraine - because of the way nerves are presses and twisted by the tense muscles.
Do not be afraid of getting a bulky neck: not all exercises do that. You can try yoga and pilates inspired moves such as trying to elongate and position your neck.